# Find nested children of li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know it is ugly, but I need to find out how to get the attribute of `<a>` tag, of each `<li>` that has a `<span>` with class `jqx-checkbox-check-checked`, if the `<li>` contains another set of `<ul><li>`. Only direct `<span>` will be check for the desired class(`jqx-checkbox-check-checked`)

This is the code sample:

```
<li>
    <span></span>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="jqx-checkbox-default jqx-rc-all">
                <span  class="jqx-checkbox-check-checked"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="jqx-rc-all jqxtree item">
        <a href="5.1"><b style="color:black"> item1</b></a>
    </span>
    <ul class="jqx-tree-dropdown" >
        <li >
            <span class="jqx-tree-item-arrow-collapse jqx-disableselect"></span>
            <div class="chkbox jqx-checkbox">
                <div>
                    <div class="jqx-checkbox-default jqx-rc-all">
                        <span  class="jqx-checkbox-check-checked"></span> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="jqx-rc-all jqx-tree-item">
                <a href="5.1.1"> item2 </a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li >
            <span class="jqx-tree-item-arrow-collapse jqx-disableselect"></span>
            <div class=""><div>
            <div class="jqx-checkbox-default jqx-rc-all" >
                <span class="jqx-checkbox-check-checked"></span>
            </div></div></div>
            <span class="jqx-rc-all jqx-tree-item">
                <a href="5.1.2"><b style="color:black"> item3</b></a>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

I know it is not simple! but if someone can show me the right jquery approach,  I will be more then grateful

Comment: You should format your HTML code to make it clearer. Based on the question it appears that the `span` or `a` tag you're looking for is a direct child of the `li` tag, but that's not the case looking at the HTML - it seems to be under a `div` tag.

Comment: By "direct child" I mean that the span belnog to the closet li parent

Comment: This HTML is ugly as sin.  In particular, you have *way* too many divs and spans.  Those should be replaced with semantic equivalents whenever possible.  `<div><div><div class="stuff"><span class="..."></span></div></div></div>`?  Now you're just messing with us.

Comment: @cHao - agreed, the HTML needs cleanup and formatting, and much better solutions would arise out of it instead of just bandaging.

Comment: this html was genrete with a jquery treeview plugin(it was much more ugly but I cleared it as much as I could)but those html tags are necessary for the right solution.

Comment: I don't if I did anything wrong while formatting your code, but there are too many closing tags around...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont fully understand your question - but I think you need to have a read of the following jQuery methods :

- [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Using a combination of those you might be able to get a handle on the object you need

Done it :

```
$('.jqx-checkbox-check-checked').each(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().parent().parent().next().find('a')
          .attr('href'));
});
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/CEYXc/

Your HTML is all over the place ...

Comment: Nop,I tried already $('.jqx-checkbox-check-checked').closest('a').attr('href'),but the value is "undefined"

Comment: Yep guys the html is very ugly ,but not something Incomprehensible ,this demand the highest Jquery programming and a few minutes to think.